# How to get messages from yammer external network?

Tags: yammer

I used admin access_token to get the messages posted in yammer external network with yammer rest api "https://www.yammer.com/[:networkname]/api/v1/messages.json" 
but I got a 401 error I want to know is there any way to get external network messages use this api.

Answer (score 1):

Yammer's authentication system is on a per network level. If you are a part of two networks, for example, you will have two different authentication tokens, one for each network. If you have a token for one network, you can grab the token for all of your other networks using this endpoint:

GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json

More documentation around this endpoint can be found here:

http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-impersonation